# Мега меню с помощью jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, меню

Делаю меню на jQuery UI. Как сделать, чтобы все подпункты были сверху на одной линии?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По умолчанию подменю выскакивает на том же уровне, что и главное меню:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать вертикальную прокрутку и сделать стрелки?

Comment: Код выложи, чтоб понять где твоя ошибка.

Comment: да код стандартный jquery ui

Comment: Родительским элементом должен выступать не блок, на который наводишь, а весь блок с меню.

Comment: я так и беру. Позицию видимо надо задавать в скрипте.

Answer (score 1):

Получилось позиционирование

```
#menu {
    position: relative;
    top:10px;
}

.ui-menu-item {
    width: 250px;
}


.ui-menu {
    width: 250px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Я вам так и сказал сразу, но вы хотели же в скрипте то как то сделать

Comment: Думаю, `position: relative;` и `position: absolute;` там и так уже заданы.

Comment: а как сделать скроллинг списка  мышкой и при нажатии на кнопку?!